# php Mongodb "$oid is not valid for storage" error when inserting from JSON export

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I have a file with following data exported with mongodb mongoexport command:

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection Users --out Users.json --jsonArray --journal
```

Users.json contains:

```
[
    {
      "_id" : { "$oid" : "53c3e81ebb593fe827040ef7" },
      "email" : "one@email.com",
      "password" : "$2y$10$OYN9qOPa8EAU202Nsee7s.jDyT8ntHq2mBkM4wWAMxDYvARRyKmr2"
    }
]
```

I want to import data without mongoimport command, just using php client, so I do

```
$fixtures = file_get_contents($fixturesPath . '/' . $fixtureFile);
$rows = json_decode($fixtures, true);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $this->db->Users->insert($row);
}
```

var_dump of $row just before the insert is correct:

```
(
  [_id] => Array
    (
        [$oid] => 53c3e81ebb593fe827040ef7
    )

  [email] => one@email.com
  [password] => $2y$10$OYN9qOPa8EAU202Nsee7s.jDyT8ntHq2mBkM4wWAMxDYvARRyKmr2
)
```

I get the following error:

```
[MongoWriteConcernException]
localhost:27017: $oid is not valid for storage.
```

The question is, how can I do to import this data from php ?
Obviously by removing _id line it works, but I think I need this id so I can tests always with the user ids .

Comment: You need to convert serialised objects to their super type, I.e. with this case objectId/MongoId

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, uses the ["extended JSON syntax"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) standard for MongoDB. This is because JSON is not "typed" where BSON is and certain data is expected to be "typed", in this case the `ObjectId`.

So if you are dealing with JSON in the "extended syntax" form then you need to convert it:

```
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    foreach ( array_keys($row) as $key) {
        if ( $key == "_id" ) {
            $row[$key] = new \MongoId( $row[$key]['$oid'] );
        }
    }
    $this->db->Users->insert( $row );
}
```

Or something similar, as looping here would be more practical if you were "detecting" this and other types. But basically you need to "convert" any of these special types from that extended representation in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Neil Lunn, and Sammaye, are correct. They pointed me to the solution, and marked Neils as correct.

But also wanted to leave here my own solution as you can also have subdocuments I ended writing this recursive function to replace all $oid

```
private function replaceMongoIds(&$document, $name = false)
{
    foreach (array_keys($document) as $key) {
        if ($key == "_id" && isset($document[$key]['$oid'])) {
            $document[$key] = new \MongoId($document[$key]['$oid']);
        } else if ($name && is_array($document[$key]) && isset($document[$key]['$oid'])) {
            $document[$key] = new \MongoId($document[$key]['$oid']);
        } else if (is_array($document[$key]) ) {
           $this->replaceMongoIds($document[$key], $key);
        }
    }
}
```

so now my code looks like

```
$fixtures = file_get_contents($fixturesPath . '/' . $fixtureFile);
$rows = json_decode($fixtures, true);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $this->replaceMongoIds($row);
  $this->db->Users->insert($row);
}
```